# Missing sublevels on click DropDown Button using Html and CSS

Tags: html, css, html-email

I used CSS and HTML in my email to get Drop Down List. When I clicked on Drop Down Button sublevels are not visible. How would I fix this? Please Help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks and Regards,
Ramyashree

[CSS-Inline code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXfdJ.png)

[Output of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNs0G.png)

```
    <div class="dropdown" style="position: relative;display: inline-block;">
     <button class="dropbtn" style="padding: 16px;font-size: 16px;border: none;cursor: pointer;">Dropdown</button>
     <div class="dropdown-content" style="display: none;position: absolute;min-width: 160px;box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);z-index: 1;">
      <a href="#" style="color: black;padding: 12px 16px;text-decoration: none;display: block;">Yes</a>
      <a href="#" style="color: black;padding: 12px 16px;text-decoration: none;display: block;">No</a>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: why don't you use Select and option tags of HTML for the dropdown list?

Comment: Please show your code. it is better than an image for help. preferably show a code-snippet for run output.

Comment: @SakshiMahajan because, I want to add multilevel drop down in future.

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi Added now.

Comment: @Ramyashreebk you are adding display: none in dropdown-content class maybe you should add display block in focus state so whenever the button in focus then list would be shown.

Answer (score 1):

You should define an `onclick` event for `button`:

```css
.block {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown" style="position: relative;display: inline-block;">
  <button class="dropbtn" onclick="dropdown()" style="padding: 16px;font-size: 16px;border: none;cursor: pointer;">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown" style="display: none;position: absolute;min-width: 160px;box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);z-index: 1;">
    <a href="#" style="color: black;padding: 12px 16px;text-decoration: none;display: block;">Yes</a>
    <a href="#" style="color: black;padding: 12px 16px;text-decoration: none;display: block;">No</a>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function dropdown() {
    document.getElementById("dropdown").classList.add("block");
  }
</script>
```

Or use `focus` pseudo class:

```css
.dropbtn:focus + .dropdown-content {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown" style="position: relative;display: inline-block;">
  <button class="dropbtn" style="padding: 16px;font-size: 16px;border: none;cursor: pointer;">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content" style="display: none;position: absolute;min-width: 160px;box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);z-index: 1;">
    <a href="#" style="color: black;padding: 12px 16px;text-decoration: none;display: block;">Yes</a>
    <a href="#" style="color: black;padding: 12px 16px;text-decoration: none;display: block;">No</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps you missed that this was for HTML Email, where for example JavaScript is strictly forbidden

Comment: @Nathan Hi. I don't understand your meaning about `JavaScript is strictly forbidden. But my second solution did it without javascript. and this is better than the first.

Comment: I mean that in an email environment, JavaScript will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can get anything worthwhile out of this. Any action from this would require JavaScript, which gets stripped out in HTML Email.

To get something happening in email, you need to use form elements, select and option. See https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-interactive-forms-in-email/

Comment: But my second solution is only with CSS.

Comment: Yes but if he wants the click to do anything in the HTML email, then it needs to use form elements. I guess if it's just an external link, it will work, but that part wasn't explained.